# How to I use UPawnMovementComponent in Ue4 C++ instead of UFloatingPawnMovement to move a pawn?

Tags: c++, game-engine, unreal-engine4, game-development

I am having trouble figuring out how to use UPawnMovementComponent instead of UFloatingPawnMovement to move a pawn. Every time I implemented UPawnMovementComponent and hit play, the editor crashed. Here's the code.

PlayerCharacter.h

```
    // Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Pawn.h"
#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/SpringArmComponent.h"
#include "Components/CapsuleComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/PawnMovementComponent.h"
#include "PlayerCharacter.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class LEARNING_API APlayerCharacter : public APawn
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this pawn's properties
    APlayerCharacter();

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Components")
    UStaticMeshComponent* PlayerMesh;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Components")
    UCameraComponent* Camera;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Components")
    USpringArmComponent* CameraArm;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = "Components")
    UCapsuleComponent* CapsuleComponent;

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    void MoveForward(float Amount);
    void MoveRight(float Amount);
    void Turn(float Amount);
    void LookUp(float Amount);

    PawnMovementComponent* PawnMovement;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

};
```

PlayerCharacter.cpp

```
    // Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.


#include "PlayerCharacter.h"

// Sets default values
APlayerCharacter::APlayerCharacter()
{
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    // Default to Player 0
    AutoPossessPlayer = EAutoReceiveInput::Player0;

    // Player Mesh and make it a root component
    PlayerMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("Player Mesh"));
    RootComponent = PlayerMesh;

    // Capsule Component
    CapsuleComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCapsuleComponent>(TEXT("Capsule Component"));
    float capsule_radius = 40.f;
    float capsule_height = 80.f;
    CapsuleComponent->InitCapsuleSize(capsule_radius, capsule_height);
    CapsuleComponent->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);

    // Spring Arm Component
    CameraArm = CreateDefaultSubobject<USpringArmComponent>(TEXT("Camera Arm"));
    CameraArm->SetRelativeRotation(FRotator(0.f, 0.f, 0.f));
    CameraArm->TargetArmLength = 500.f;
    CameraArm->bEnableCameraLag = true;
    CameraArm->CameraLagSpeed = 3.f;
    CameraArm->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);

    // Camera
    Camera = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("Camera Component"));
    Camera->SetupAttachment(CameraArm, USpringArmComponent::SocketName);

    // Player Movement Component
    PawnMovement= CreateDefaultSubobject<UPawnMovementComponent>(TEXT("Pawn Movement"));
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void APlayerCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    
}

// Called every frame
void APlayerCharacter::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void APlayerCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveForward", this, &APlayerCharacter::MoveForward);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveRight", this, &APlayerCharacter::MoveRight);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("Turn", this, &APlayerCharacter::Turn);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("LookUp", this, &APlayerCharacter::LookUp);
}

void APlayerCharacter::MoveForward(float Amount)
{
    PawnMovement->AddInputVector(GetActorForwardVector() * Amount);
}

void APlayerCharacter::MoveRight(float Amount)
{
    PawnMovement->AddInputVector(GetActorRightVector() * Amount);
}

void APlayerCharacter::Turn(float Amount)
{
    AddControllerYawInput(Amount);
}

void APlayerCharacter::LookUp(float Amount)
{
    AddControllerPitchInput(Amount);
}
```

The reason I want to implement UPawnMovementComponent rather than UFloatingPawnMovement is because I don't want a floating pawn that moves around in the air, I want the pawn to only move on the ground. I reckon that the UPawnMovementComponent will allow me to do that. Like I said, every time I implemented, compile it, and the ran it, the editor crashed. So is there any way to implement it without the editor crashing.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you ever solved this or not (the question is pretty old) but I believe that you can't initialize a `UPawnMovementComponent` directly, you need to derive your own. If you look at the class declaration you can see that the `UPawnMovementComponent` is marked as `UCLASS(abstract)`. See the [declaration here](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/5df54b7ef1714f28fb5da319c3e83d96f0bedf08/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Classes/GameFramework/PawnMovementComponent.h#L21)

Also, if you try checking that `PawnMovement` is not a `nullptr` before making any calls to it you'll prevent a crash.

Comment: I'm getting error UFloatingPawnMovement is undefined. Can u help me, I'm on unreal 4.27 with VS 22. Game Dev option is selected in VS installation

Comment: I have not installed Editor Symbol for debugging(sadly its 36 GB) and no Target Plattforms have been download for unreal, Is any of them required.